# How to combine three table to find Avg,High,Low value in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have three different tables such as

```
  prac_test
UID | net_wpm
5        58
5        67

 multi_test
UID | net_wpm
5        88
5        97

 shadow_test
UID | net_wpm
5        8
5        77
```

How to combine these three tables and get avg,High,Low net wpm for UID  5

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

try use `union all` + `avg` + `max` + `min`

```
select avg(`net_wpm`) `avg`,max(`net_wpm`) High,min(`net_wpm`) Low from (
  select * from prac_test union all
  select * from multi_test union all
  select * from shadow_test
) T
group by `UID`
```

[Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a6f67/6/0)

**Result:**

```
| UID |     avg | High | Low |
|-----|---------|------|-----|
|   5 | 65.8333 |   97 |   8 |
```